# Unable to open VS code extension preview server with local chrome

Tags: javascript, html, performance, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-extension

Whenever I try to launch any file on browser using preview server extension I got this error:

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.

I tried the following steps from [here](https://windowsreport.com/chrome-access-network-firewall/) on **1. Add Chrome to Windows Firewall** on my desktop settings but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the the port you are trying to use is unavailable. Did you try to restart your device?

Comment: Cool. That fixed it! Thank you!